# \RequirePackage{tocloft} doesn't work before \documentclass

Tags: tocloft

`\RequirePackage` is supposed to work before `\documentclass` and, indeed, the following MCE works like a charm:

```
\RequirePackage{url}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\url{foo}
\end{document}
```

But, in the case of the `tocloft` package, this doesn't work. Indeed, the following MCE fails to compile with the following error message:

> `! LaTeX Error: Command \cftdot undefined.`

```
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\ensuremath{\ast}}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite at the start of `toclosft.sty` (lines 36-45) you find

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}{%
  \@cfthaschapterfalse
  \@ifundefined{section}{%
    \PackageWarning{tocloft}%
      {I don't recognize any sectional divisions so I'll do nothing}
    \renewcommand{\@cftquit}{\endinput}
    }{\PackageInfo{tocloft}{The document has section divisions}}
  }{\@cfthaschaptertrue
    \PackageInfo{tocloft}{The document has chapter divisions}}
\@cftquit
```

Of course, loading the package before `\documentclass` means that there are no `\section`s & Co. Indeed you first get the warning

```
Package tocloft Warning: I don't recognize any sectional divisions so I'll do
nothing on input line 44.
```

Then `\@cftquit` is executed, which has been defined to be `\endinput`. No further code from the `tocloft` package is run, and you never get to the definition of `\cftdot` (which is on line 162).

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Too bad `tocloft` doesn't check for this later, e.g. `\AtBeginDocument`: it would have been helpful for classes which load packages that need `tocloft` to be loaded before them, such as `etoc`.