# If \RequirePackage{tocloft} doesn't work before \documentclass, how do I require the package?

Tags: errors, tocloft, package-writing

I want to define a new list of things using `\newlistof` in the `tocloft` package.  I included `tocloft` in the usual way for packages (`\RequirePackage{tocloft}`; full minimal code below).  However, when I run it through `pdflatex`, I get:

> `Package tocloft Warning: I don't recognize any sectional divisions so I'll do nothing on input line ##.`
>
> ...
>
> `! Undefined control sequence.`
>
> `<recently read> \newlistof`
>
> `l.## \newlistof`

I found that someone else had [the same problem but for `\cftdot`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511301/requirepackagetocloft-doesnt-work-before-documentclass) rather than `\newlistof`.  That user asked what was going on rather than how to actually include the `tocloft` package, so now I know it's because `tocloft` is implemented to fail if it doesn't find any chapters, sections, etc.  But I'm still none the wiser about how to include `tocloft`.  I could find nothing else of relevance on the internet or in the documentation.

(Using `\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}`, which is how I want to use it, gives `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'titles' for package 'tocloft'.`, which is presumably for the same sort of reason.)

Instead of `\RequirePackage{tocloft}`, I tried:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{tocloft}}
...
\newlistof{things}{tng}{\listthingsname}
```

so that it would load at the start of the document, but I get the same `Undefined control sequence` error (presumably because there are still no sectional divisions at that point).  Commenting `\newlistof` out gives:

> `Package tocloft Warning: \@starttoc has already been redefined; tocloft bailing out. on input line 1156.`

My question is how can I include `tocloft` in a *.dtx file?  (I'm using the `etoolbox` package, if that helps.)

---

**MWE** (or rather minimum example that shows my initial attempt ):

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/things}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{things}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
% \AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{tocloft}}
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{things}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
% \title{Title}
% \author{Author}
% \date{\today}
%
% \maketitle
% ^^A\listofthings
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%
\ newcommand{\listthingsname}{List of Things}
\newlistof{things}{tng}{\listthingsname}
%
% \newcommand{\thing}[1]{%
%   \refstepcounter{things}\textsuperscript{\thethings}#1%
%   \addcontentsline{tng}{things}{\protect{\thethings}#1}%
% }
%
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Comment: your dtx structure is rather weird, you sue \jobname but it only works if the file is called things.dtx as you include that package by name, the error is because you need the driver code earlier (or the package code guarded by `% \iffalse` so that when you do `pdflatex things.dtx` it _only_ sees the `<driver>` section, as it is you are processing the `<package>` section before the documentclass has been loaded

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I based my *.dtx file on [A model .dtx file](https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/) – it was all I could find that explained how to write a *.dtx package. I confess it's all a little over my head. The file is indeed called things.dtx – should I change `\usepackage{things}` to `\usepackage{\jobname}`? If I move the `<driver>` section to before the `<package>` section, it seems to work – is that a more standard dtx structure?

Comment: yes moving the driver up would be a good solution, you could post a self answer if you have a working version

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Carlisle pointed out that my dtx structure wasn't quite right.  The `<driver>` section, which includes `\begindocument`, needs to be processed before the `<package>` section that includes the `\RequirePackage` commands.  Therefore, moving the `<driver>` section to before that `<package>` section fixes the problem: `\begindocument` is called before any packages are required.

I also reverted `\usepackage{things}` to `\usepackage{\jobname}` because of David's comment.  I'm not sure why I changed it in the first place :)

---

**MWE** (fixed)

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/things}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{things}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
% \AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{tocloft}}
% \AtEndDocument{\usepackage{tocloft}}
%</package>
% \fi
%
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
% \title{Title}
% \author{Author}
% \date{\today}
%
% \maketitle
% \listofthings
%
% \thing{A thing}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%
\newrobustcmd{\listthingsname}{List of Things}
\newlistof{things}{tng}{\listthingsname}
%
\newrobustcmd{\thing}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{things}\textsuperscript{\thethings}#1%
  \addcontentsline{tng}{things}{\protect\numberline{\thethings}#1}%
}
%
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
```